# Puppeteer using google fonts in headers and footer in Node.js serverless AWS lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, puppeteer, serverless-framework

I am using Node.js AWS lambda with serverless framework, The PDF generation is working fine, Now I have a requirement to use custom fonts in headers and footer section, I have tried to add the google fonts using layer in serverless and also tried to import the fonts through css it's is not working in both ways does anyone knows how can we use custom fonts in Header and Footer using puppeteer.

Below is my helper class that generates the PDF:

```
import * as chromium from "chrome-aws-lambda";
import { GetPDFBuffer } from "./types/HelperTypes";

export class Helper {
  static getPDFBuffer: GetPDFBuffer = async (html: string, options: any) => {
    let browser = null;
    try {
      const executablePath = process.env.IS_OFFLINE
        ? null
        : await chromium.executablePath;
      browser = await chromium.puppeteer.launch({
        args: chromium.args,
        executablePath,
      });

      const page = await browser.newPage();
      const loaded = page.waitForNavigation({
        waitUntil: "networkidle0",
      });
      await page.setContent(html, { "waitUntil": ['load', 'domcontentloaded', 'networkidle0'] });
     
      await loaded;
      return await page.pdf(options);
    } catch (error) {
      return error;
    } finally {
      if (browser !== null) {
        await browser.close();
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Why you don't use google font link, like `@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Signika);`

Comment: It works in body of the PDF but not in the header and footer templates.

Comment: Any updates on this? Im facing the same issue.

Comment: Same issue here too

Answer (score 0):

Headers and footers have some limitations regarding external styling.

If you want to use a custom google font, you'll have to download the font and install it as a system font and chrome will pick it up automatically from your font-family rule.

Example:

1. Download https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans
2. Install the font per your OS's instructions.  Font Book is used on a mac for example.
3. Reference the font as you would any other system font in your header or footer:

```html
<style>
  footer {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Yes, this could work but given that the service is running in aws-lambda you cannot install all the fonts you want due to lambda size restriction :thinking:

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chromium, you can load the font with `chromium.font(url)` as these fonts are available in the header and footer.  This avoids the complexity of installing the font in the Lambda architecture.

Example:

```js
    let browser = null;
    // load Open Sans from Google
    await chromium.font('http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v6/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3aCWcynf_cDxXwCLxiixG1c.ttf');
```